# How to get a Deterministic computed value for Date + Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a table that has a datetime and a time field where the datetime is actually just the date and the time field is the time. I need to combine these 2 fields to create a "created_time" computed field. I'd like to persist this computed field but I keep getting a "non-deterministic" error when I'm trying to combine them. Firstly, I'm not sure I understand why it's non-determinstic, but secondly, is there any fancy way to get around that and accomplish this?

```
--------------------------------------------------------
       date (datetime)           |       time (varchar)
--------------------------------------------------------
2021-05-05 00:00:00              | 12:00
2021-05-13 00:00:00              | 18:01
```

I've tried using the following computations and neither work.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD created_time AS ([date] + [time]) PERSISTED

ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD created_time AS (DATEADD(millisecond, DATEDIFF(millisecond, 0, [time]), [date])) PERSISTED
```

Comment: What are the data types of the other two columns? The second version should work with `date` and `time` respectively http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0d84b

Comment: Well then how about change `time` column to a sensible datatype, like maybe `time`??

Comment: @Charlieface The date is a ```datetime``` and the time is a ```varchar```.

Comment: @Charlieface That's a bigger change than what I was hoping to make, though it makes sense. I didn't build the table, so I'm well aware that's ideal. I suppose the reason it's non-deterministic as a varchar is because it's having to cast it to a time huh?

Comment: I was able to get it to work if I manually used ```CONVERT``` on the time field. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the `+` operator is not valid for `date` and `time` values, strange as it may seem. So you need to use your second version.

**Secondly, your `time` column is actually `varchar`, so the conversion is an implicit non-deterministic conversion.**

You can make it deterministic by using `CONVERT` with a deterministic style parameter, such as 108 in this case:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.[table] ADD created_time AS
  (DATEADD(millisecond,
      DATEDIFF(millisecond, 0, CONVERT(time, [time], 108)),
  [date])) PERSISTED;
```

[This is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15#built-in-function-determinism), some style parameters are not deterministic, because it can depend on culture and century (where year is two-digits).

**I strongly suggest you either convert your `time` column into the `time` data type, or better yet, change it to a combined `datetime` column:**

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.[table]
  ALTER COLUMN [time] time NOT NULL;

-- or
ALTER TABLE dbo.[table] ADD created_time datetime NULL;

UPDATE dbo.[table]
SET created_time = (DATEADD(millisecond,
      DATEDIFF(millisecond, 0, CONVERT(time, [time], 108)),
  [date]));

ALTER TABLE dbo.[table]
  DROP COLUMN [time]
  DROP COLUMN [date];

ALTER TABLE dbo.[table] ALTER created_time datetime NOT NULL;
```